# can't load ggmap package in jupyter

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, conda

I used `conda install -c vfonov r-ggmap` to install ggmap package. When I tried to load the package in Jupyter notebook, I got the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggmap’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/anaconda3/lib/R/library/jpeg/libs/jpeg.so':
  dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/R/library/jpeg/libs/jpeg.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjpeg.9.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/R/library/jpeg/libs/jpeg.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: jpeg.so requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.9.dylib provides version 12.0.0
Traceback:

1. library(ggmap)
2. tryCatch({
 .     attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
 .     ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 .     env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)
 . }, error = function(e) {
 .     P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e))) 
 .         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])
 .     else ""
 .     msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s", 
 .         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))
 .     if (logical.return) 
 .         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)
 .     else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
 . })
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. value[[3L]](cond)
6. stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: The error message is informative: `Incompatible library version: jpeg.so requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.9.dylib provides version 12.0.0`. Looks like you need `jpeg.so` version `13.0.0` but are getting `12.0.0` from `libjpeg.9.dylib` so you need to go update that...how you do that I'm not sure...

Comment: Indeed. However I did everything I could to try to upgrade `libjpeg`, all failed. It seems there is not `jpeg.so 13.0.0` at all...

Answer (score 1):

The solution is surprisingly easy.

`conda install -c conda-forge jpeg`

done.